# OpenStreetMap Api call returns empty set

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to call OpenStreetMap API:
http://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/map?bbox=43.65,-79.38,43.66,-79.37

It returns no error, but map is empty:

Do you have any ideas why?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think for the given request, the empty dataset delivered is actually the correct response.

The [API documentation](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/API_v0.6#Retrieving_map_data_by_bounding_box%3a_GET_.2Fapi.2F0.6.2Fmap) says `api/0.6/map` returns

> - All nodes that are inside a given bounding box and any relations that reference them.
> - All ways that reference at least one node that is inside a given bounding box, any relations that reference them [the ways], and any
>     nodes outside the bounding box that the ways may reference.
> - All relations that reference one of the nodes, ways or relations included due to the above rules. (Does not apply recursively, see
>     explanation below.)

As far as I can see, your bounding box selects a bit of Antarctica. What data did you expect?

I guess, in OSM, Antarctica is just a way, describing its outline (and maybe some research stations somewhere). If you now ask for an area in the middle of nowhere there, there are no data to get. This is because within your bbox there are no nodes. The way for the outline/area of Antarctica is only fetched if at least one of its nodes lies within your bounding box.

PS: If you want a piece of Toronto (with lots of data), swap longitude and latitude values :)

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Download#Construct_a_URL_for_the_HTTP_API

it says the bounding box can only be 0.5 by 0.5 degrees. it also says you might want to try XAPI for such a large area